# Replace String with dynamicaly ending in php

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a large String, containing "items1" and "items2" ...
I don't know how much of these items exists. So I don't know until which number it is counting.

Now I need to replace all these parts of the String to "items"

Example:

```
asdfHelloBla"items2"HahaHabicht"items3"test => asdfHelloBla"items"HahaHabicht"items"test
```

Can anyone help me? 
Can I do this with regular expressions?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove digits that appear after a static string `item` inside double quotes? Did you try anything?

Comment: Where's the input coming from? That doesn't look like anything sane.

Comment: @JonStirling: Consisder a random string.

Comment: Will there be quotes inside the input string? Or are those just for clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the following code:

```
<?php
    $string = 'asdfHelloBla"items2"HahaHabicht"items3"';
    $to_replace = array('"items1"', '"items2"', '"items3"');
    echo str_replace($to_replace, '"items"', $string);
?>
```

the str_replace function is used as follows:

```
str_replace(search, replace, subject);
```

It can accept an array as the 'search' argument and then replaces any of the matches with the 'replace' argument. 
You need to add all you want to replace in the $to_replace array that is in this case "item1", "item2" and so on and it should work fine. One more thing, you need to know the maximum limit till where the list goes.
If you know the maximum limit, you can use a loop to replace '"item1"', '"item2"'.... with '"item{$n}"' 
Hope this helps :)